# Maya turns screen brightness to max every time I press or hold spacebar

Tags: maya

The system is Windows 10, and Maya version is 2022. Whenever I press spacebar to switch to 4-view, it briefly turns the screen brightness to max. It returns to normal after I release spacebar.
[image: normal brightness]

[image: brightness when spacebar pressed]

It's making things difficult to work with at night as the brightness will shoot up every time I switch views.
None of my other programs on this computer changes screen brightness when I press spacebar in them.
I can't seem to find any answers online so I figured I'd ask experienced users of Maya. Please help

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about how to develop a game. I think you might get better answers on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). If you choose to ask the question there, be sure to delete the copy here, to keep all the answers together in one place.

Comment: okay I'll try that thank you